# Edit form not grabbing value used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a form (formtastic) that is using the Date::DAYNAMES helper to output the days of the week in a select box:

```
days = Date::DAYNAMES
q.input :day,
collection: days,
as: :select
```

This works and outputs the days of the week starting from Sunday, however when it comes to editing that same form the field in question does not remember what day I have previously selected, it just returns the same dropdown (defaults to a blank field).

Form:

```
# Activity Date/Time Entry
f.inputs class: 'activityDayTime' do
  f.has_many :activity_dates do |q|
    days = Date::DAYNAMES
    if q.object.new_record?
      q.input :day,
              collection: days,
              as: :select
      q.input :time_from
      q.input :time_to
    else
      q.input :day,
              collection: days,
              as: :select
      q.input :time_from
      q.input :time_to
      q.input :_destroy,
              as: :boolean,
              required: :false,
              label: 'Remove Day/Time'
    end
  end
end
```

How can I tell the form to default to the saved day within the edit form?

### Edit

After checking the DB it seems the days is actually saving (showing as nil), so there seems to be something wrong with Date::DAYNAMES saving into a date field

### Edit 2

I have changed the date field to a string field but the day still saves as nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# app/helpers/collection_helper
module CollectionHelper
  def days_collection
    (0..6).map { |wday| [Date::DAYNAMES[wday], wday] }
  end
end

# app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
. . .
  = select_tag :month, options_for_select(days_collection, Time.now.day) # or collection helper
  # simple_form
  = f.input :month, as: :select, collection: days_collection
  # formastic
  = f.input :author, as: :select, collection: days_collection
. . .
```

#### Explanation:

A day stores as integer in rails

```
Post.first.created_at.wday # => 2
```

So we need to associate day name with its number

```
Date::DAYNAMES
=> [ "Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" ]
```

This we can achieve with the code (one of implementations of it)

```
(0..6).map { |wday| [Date::DAYNAMES[wday], wday] }
# => [ [ "Sunday", 0],[ "Monday",1], ["Tuesday", 2], # end etc
```

This is format of array which is needed for collection builder for formastic and simple form also.
Wish it helps.

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining what is happening here please, also get this error  unexpected '}', expecting '=' (SyntaxError)

Comment: I did, and fixed typo here: `[Date::DAYNAMES[day], day]` (first square bracket)

Comment: the day is still saving as nil :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49071/discussion-between-itsnikolay-and-richlewis)

Comment: for me is also `<%= f.input :wday, as: :select, collection: Date::DAYNAMES %>` get worked